# What is the error in the energy consumption problem in cplex listed below?

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl, energy

```
int N=...;              //Number of trips.
range n=1..N;           //a
 
 
int I=...;              //Number of previous stops.
range i=1..I;           //b
 
float H=...;            //High value.
float L=...;            //Low value.
 
float Ei[n][i] = ...;   //Energy at previous stop during departure.
float Dij[n][i] = ...;  //Energy consumption in travelling from previous stop to cuttrnt stop.
float Eij[n][i] = ...;  //Energy charged at current stop.
float Ej[n][i] = ...;   //Energy at current stop during departure.

dvar boolean Xs[a in n][b in i];        //decision variable to place chargine station or not.

execute
{
  (for(a in n,b in i)
  
        if(a==1,b==1)
            {
                Ei[a][b]== H;
            }               
        else
        
            (Ei[a][b]==previous(Ej[a][b]));
            

    for(a in n,b in i)      //Energy at current stop.
                            
        Ej[a,b]==Ei[a][b]-Dij[a][b] +Xs[a][b]*Eij[a][b];
    );              
                            
};


minimize    //minimize the total energy charged ie. sumproduct of decision variable multiplied by energy charged.
  sum(a in n,b in i) Xs[a][b]*Eij[a][b];    
  
subject to {
    
    forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ej[a,b]<=H;
      
     forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ej[a,b]>=H;
        
     forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ei[a,b]<=H;
      
     forall(a in n,b in i)  
      Ei[a,b]>=H;
      
};
```

where the dat file includes following value

```
N=3;

I=4;


H=80;

L=24;

Dij=    [
    [10.0,12,9,8],
    [10.0,12,9,8],
    [10.0,12,9,8]
        ];

Eij=    [
    [6,7.5,4.5,7.5],
    [6,7.5,4.5,7.5],
    [6,7.5,4.5,7.5]
        ];
```

what might be the error in the code as the model is not being loaded. Is there anything wrong with the execute statement? Can we use execute statement to find the vale of Ej[n][i] and other value of Ei[n][i] which requires the value of decision variable? Is there anyway that we can execute this problem in cplex opl?

Answer (score 0):

```
int N=...;              //Number of trips.
range n=1..N;           //a
 
 
int I=...;              //Number of previous stops.
range i=1..I;           //b
 
float H=...;            //High value.
float L=...;            //Low value.
 
float Ei[n][i];   //Energy at previous stop during departure.
float Dij[n][i] = ...;  //Energy consumption in travelling from previous stop to cuttrnt stop.
float Eij[n][i] = ...;  //Energy charged at current stop.
float Ej[n][i];   //Energy at current stop during departure.

dvar boolean Xs[a in n][b in i];        //decision variable to place chargine station or not.

execute
{
  for(a in n) for(b in i)
  
        if(a==1,b==1)
            {
                Ei[a][b]== H;
            }               
//        else
//        
//            (Ei[a][b]==previous(Ej[a][b]));
            

    for(a in n) for(b in i)      //Energy at current stop.
                            
        Ej[a][b]=Ei[a][b]-Dij[a][b]; // +Xs[a][b]*Eij[a][b];
    ;              
                            
};


minimize    //minimize the total energy charged ie. sumproduct of decision variable multiplied by energy charged.
  sum(a in n,b in i) Xs[a][b]*Eij[a][b];    
  
subject to {
    
    forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ej[a,b]<=H;
      
     forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ej[a,b]>=H;
        
     forall(a in n,b in i)
      Ei[a,b]<=H;
      
     forall(a in n,b in i)  
      Ei[a,b]>=H;
      
};
```

works better and can help you understand what was wrong from a syntax point of view.

In an [execute block](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/) you can either do preprocess, postprocess , or flow control but not really write constraint.